# Display largest items in dictionary based off of the value of the key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary, and I want to display the three largest items, but I want it to be based off the int value of the key.  Here is the code:

```
cust_numb = int(input("Enter number of unique customers then press enter:"))
list_customer = {}
customers = 1
for y in range(0,cust_numb):
    purch_numb = int(input("How many purchases did customer %s have % 
(customers)))
    list_customer.update({"customer{}".format(customers) : purch_numb})
    customers = customers + 1

info = ""
for customer in range(0,cust_numb):
    info += "%s " % ("customer {}".format(customer+1)) + "had %s " % 
(list_customer["customer{}".format(customer+1)]) + "purchases. "

info = dict(dictionary)
```

I couldn't find this online, and any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. Please show example input and the wanted output.

Comment: So say the dictionary is Customer 1: 4, customer 2: 6, customer 3: 1, customer 4: 9, customer 5: 2 ---- I want it to return Customer 1, customer 2, customer 4

Comment: So you want to return the keys of the three largest values in the dictionary? (In no particular order?)

Comment: Preferably it would return in the ordered entered, (fifth line of the code).

Comment: What's wrong with the code? We need more information to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no straightforward ways as dictionary is not typically used in such scenario. It requires some list comprehension, or some other work around. Below is one way, which forms a sorted list of values, then fetches the key corresponding to these sorted list of values.

```
d     = {'a':2,'b':1,'c':5,'d':0}
sList = sorted(d.values())
op    = []
for i in sList:
  op.append([k for k,v in d.items() if v == i][0])
print (op)
```